# Find $f(E) $ and an explicit formula for $f^{-1}$ on $f(E)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inverse-function

Find $f(E) $ and an explicit formula for  $f^{-1}$ on $f(E)$.

1). $f(x)=x^2+2x-5$, $E=(-\infty,-6]$

Here what I tried if there is any mistakes please tell me,

First by looking at graphs I found,

$f(E)=[19,\infty)$ then I solved for $f(x)=y$ then I got two result
$x=-1 \pm (y+6)^{1/2}$ Since question is said find a formula, I think  both are correct on $f(E)$ but it is no sure!!! Is it correct?

Comment: Hint: the domain of $f$ is $E$. So the range of $f^{-1}$ must be a subset of $E$; that is, for all $y\in f(E)$, $f^{-1}(y)$ must belong to $E$.

Comment: @TonyK If so answer is $-1 - (y+6)^{1/2}$  one. is it correct?

Comment: Correct!${}{}{}$

Comment: @TonyK Thanks!-